# Same x-axis for two different subplots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, subplot

I want have a line and bar plot in a figure in MATLAB. How can I have same x-axis for both graphs? The below bar plot x-axis should be same as above x-axis. I want retain the ability of comparing figures.

Figure link: [Click Here](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=9688135440)

Comment: I think there is a problem in photo uploading. I added link of the figure.

Comment: Your figure link doesn't seem to work any more...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `linkaxes` function:

```
figure
ax1 = subplot(2,2,1);
x1 = linspace(0,6);
y1 = sin(x1);
plot(x1,y1)

ax2 = subplot(2,2,2);
x2 = linspace(0,10);
y2 = sin(2*x2);
plot(x2,y2)

ax3 = subplot(2,2,[3,4]);
x3 = linspace(0,16);
y3 = sin(6*x3);
plot(x3,y3)

linkaxes([ax1,ax2,ax3],'x')
```

usage:

> `linkaxes(ax)` links the x- and y-axis limits of the `Axes` objects specified
>   in the vector `ax`. The `linkaxes` function chooses limits that incorporate the
>   current limits for all the linked axes.
>
> `linkaxes(ax, option)` links the axes `ax` according to the specified `option`.
>   The `option` argument can be one of these values:
>
> `'x'`     Link x-axis only.
>   `'y'`     Link y-axis only.
>   `'xy'`    Link x-axis and y-axis.
>   `'off'`   Remove linking.

Reference here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html

If you have a matlab older than 2006 you can follow this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7169-samexaxis-nice-subplots-with-same-x-axis